# Java scrolling through jbuttons

Tags: java, jframe, scroll, jpanel, jbutton

Ok here is my problem...
I have this jframe with a jpanel inside. And in that  jpanel there is about 30 jbuttons stacked under eachother. But only 17 can be veiwed at a time. Is there a way i can scroll down worts to see the rest?
Btw im not looking for `JScrollPane`

Comment: Add your panel to `JScrollPane` and then use it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html Please refer this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a scroll pane, that seems to be the best solution here!,if the size of the buttons exceeds the frame area ,do they ?

Comment: No they go out of the frame